# C# equivalent of Character.digit of Java

Tags: java, c#, char

I have the following code in Java which I am trying to rewrite in C#.

```
byte b = ...;

int i = Character.digit((char)b, 16);
```

Is there anything equivalent to Character.digit in C#

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit(char,%20int)

Returns the numeric value of the character ch in the specified radix.

Answer (score 6):

You have to implement it *manually*, something like this:

```
public static int Digit(char value, int radix) {
  if ((radix <= 0) || (radix > 36))
    return -1; // Or throw exception

  if (radix <= 10) 
    if (value >= '0' && value < '0' + radix)
      return value - '0';
    else
      return -1;
  else if (value >= '0' && value <= '9')
    return value - '0';
  else if (value >= 'a' && value < 'a' + radix - 10)
    return value - 'a' + 10;
  else if (value >= 'A' && value < 'A' + radix - 10)
    return value - 'A' + 10;

  return -1;
}
```